# Changing Row Source of a Lookup depending on another field

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to define the row source of a lookup field by selecting the table name from a separate lookup box.

The catalog of products comprises of about 41 Product Groups, which are then further divided into Types, some of which have over 100 types.

I have a table of Product Groups (41 groups), and I then have a separate table of Types for each Product Group (41 tables). All Type table names are exactly as they appear on the Product Group table. I want to be able to  select the Product Group from a Lookup Box, and then select the Type from the corresponding table in a separate lookup box.

The images below should help give an idea of what I'm looking to do.

Set up of my first lookup box:

[image]

Set up of my second lookup:

[image]

Is this possible, and if so can anyone lend a hand ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use VBA? Is the structure of the database normalized? It would be easier to do this if all product types were in the same table, with a foreign key to their related Product Group. Otherwise you will need to use VBA to extract the tbl name and update the recordsource of your second combobox.

Comment: That's ok, Do the product group names perfectly match the table name storing the product type? Could you provide a few examples of a group and the table and table name that corresponds to it? Are all product type tables constructed the same way (same columns and column names)?

Comment: I only have a basic knowledge. 
I had thought of using a function to set a variable = the value selected in the product group box, then setting the source of the second combobox = that variable.
I wasn't sure how to implement that though.

I have started compiling a spreadsheet with Product Groups in Column A and the Type in Column B like so:

Col. A ------------- Col. B
Group1 -----------Type1
Group1 -----------Type2
Group1 -----------Type3
Group2 -----------Type1
Group2 -----------Type2, Etc.

 which I will then import to Access and then use a simple filter on the first combo box.

Comment: You're on the right path. If you have a list of the different group/type combinations in a single table, you can write a query to only show records that match the selected value in combo1. That's the easiest approach IMO.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. 

I was trying to upload more images of my tables, but my Reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: This is really bad design. All your `Types` should be in one table with fields `TypeID, ProductGroupID` as well as any other fields you need, not as separate tables. Then you could just use a WHERE clause in your Row Source and a requery trigger on the Product Group After Update event and you would be done. Depending on how far you are in your project, consider changing the structure as above because that design will come back to bite you time and time again.

Alternatively, add a field to your Product Groups table with the table name of the corresponding Types.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize, you will need a single table with your TypeID, GroupID, and any other "Type" related fields.

Your Group ComboBox should have the ID field as its first column (makes the filtering much easier), So your control source should be:

```
SELECT [ProductGroup]![GroupID], [ProductGroup]![ProductGroup] 
FROM [ProductGroup]
ORDER BY [ProductGroup];
```

Then in the properties for Group ComboBox on the Format tab make your column width 0";x" to hide the ID field.

The control source for the Type ComboBox should be:

```
SELECT [NewTypeTable]![TypeID], [NewTypeTable]![TypeName]
FROM [NewTypeTable]
WHERE [NewTypeTable]![GroupID] Like [Forms]![frmWithComboBoxName]![CboPGroup]
ORDER BY [NewTypeTable]![TypeName];
```

And again, if you want to hide the ID field, make the first column width 0".

You should also requery the second combobox in the `afterUpdate()` event of `CboPGroup` which will filter the second combobox based on the new selection in `CboPGroup`. The code (VBA) for that would be:

```
Forms!frmWithComboBoxName!CboType.Requery
```